# Getting Data from current Year till date

Tags: mysql

I have the query where i am getting the data but one year back till now,

```
select * from tblorders 
            where CreatedDateTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

how can i get the data from the start of the current year till date data

start of the current year like `01/01/2021`

Comment: ```SELECT ... date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01') AND NOW()

Comment: 1) We don't know how your `date` data look like and what is the exact datatype for `CreatedDateTime` column. Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblorders` and sample data is required. 2) Do you want to return all dates from `2021-01-01` until now? Does the table have data for each of the date from then? If not, do you still want to show them? Expected result is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tblorders 
            where ( CreatedDateTime between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') AND NOW() )
```

This would return from the beginning of the current year till current date

Comment: this is not working as expected, it is returning me records from 2020 year,

Comment: @Snan I made a small edit to the answer: `DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') `

Comment: or CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01')

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select * from tblorders 
        where YEAR(CreatedDateTime) = YEAR(NOW());
```

DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d7h2raMmvxngn1uigPjoB5/0

Comment: same, it just returns me january month of 2021 and nothing more

Comment: @Snan It works fine - see the DBFiddle I added. Are you sure you've got any data to select?

Comment: using this will not use the index

Comment: OP said 1 yr back and till now, that means it's between clause.